# Disable the swipe/close button

Tags: android

I created an app with webview inside, the webview has an ajax that reload every 5 seconds and play some music, it works fine but when i close the app with the swipe/close button the webview is close and the music stop play, Can i disable the swipe/close button only from my app?

Comment: Fortunately, no. It is the user's device; if the user wishes to end your task, that is the user's decision.

Comment: Ok, then we don't have a way to call the webpage in background after close the app?

Comment: The way in Android that you have things work continuously in the background is through a `Service`. I have not tried using a `WebView` in a `Service` for several years. A `WebView` is a UI component; it is not designed to be used in the background. My guess is that you will be better served discarding the `WebView` and writing a traditional Android app that does what you want.